# Installation date of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, date

How can I determine when Ubuntu was installed in my computer? There was a different question posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/date-ubuntu-was-installed).

Comment: What was wrong with the answers there?  `/var/log/installer`, `/boot`, and `dumpe2fs` all look OK to me.

Comment: @Mikel. The reason is that they show different dates. For instance, dumpe2fs and /var/log/installer show creation date as 05.11.2010 while /boot shows as 29.01.2011. That is why I wanted to find out precise method to get this information without any doubts.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor Then most probably something happened to `/boot`. When `dumpe2fs` and `/var/log/installer` point to the same answer I won't keep any doubt.

Comment: All right guys. So, what do you suggest me to do with the question? Just delete it or what?

Comment: @Bakhtiyor If you still think something is wrong and you need help with it please edit your question to include that information. Or if you question has already been answered on the other site you can close this one.

Comment: For the other thread's answers, identify which method gave you a date that was *too late* . Unless there is something else wrong, an earlier non-fubar date is going to be a better answer for a born-on date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1730026&postcount=3) `sudo grep ubiquity /var/log/installer/syslog | less` should work for Ubuntu.

`last` works for Fedora.

Comment: Won't `last` suffer from the same issue with wtmp rotation?

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo dumpe2fs $(mount | awk '/on \/ /{print $1}') | grep 'created:'
```

Use this command for check when was the OS installed.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I would add "sudo" for completeness.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer as it relies on filesystem creation date rather than log file that can be modified.

Comment: this finally worked on my ubuntu server pi, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `last | tail -1`. It helped me find the installation date on Fedora 14. The last line stating

```
wtmp begins Tue Nov  9 22:35:12 2010
```

is the installation date.

Comment: wtmp begins Wed Feb  2 16:24:52 2011. This is what I get with last command in Ubuntu. Approximately my OS had been installed on November 2010.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor Try `grep ubiquity /var/log/installer/syslog | less`. I found that [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1730026&postcount=3)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that.  For example, FreeBSD rotates /var/log/wtmp by default, so when I run last on one of my FreeBSD boxes I get "wtmp begins Thu Feb  3 09:50:42 EST 2011".  My Slackware box does the same thing, I installed the OS on it years ago but last reports that wtmp began last week.  I don't have an Ubuntu box handy to check.

Comment: @Dharmit. sudo grep ubiquity /var/log/installer/syslog | less worked for me. Could you please post it as an answer, so that I could select your answer as an accepted one.

Comment: @Dharmit. I think now you can delete your first answer.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor Thanks. Your question helped me learn. I was very much interested in finding the installation date of my Fedora box so that I can boost its ROCK-SOLID STABILITY to my friends who format Windows at least once a month. But I was always lazy to Google for it. Today, after reading your question, I finally found that out. :)

Comment: `wtmp` gets rotated.  See `/etc/logrotate.conf`.

Comment: @mazianni it does on Fedora and Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 0):

When `dumpe2fs` and `findmnt` are not installed (on Synology DSM v6 for example) type :

```bash
$ sudo tune2fs -l $(LANG=C df / --output=source | grep -v Filesystem) | grep created:
Filesystem created:       Sat Jan  1 01:00:09 2000
```

If a least `findmnt` is installed (on another system), type :

```bash
$ sudo tune2fs -l $(findmnt -n -o source -T /) | grep created:
Filesystem created:       Wed Sep  8 18:15:47 2021
```