# How do I find how long ago a Linux system was installed?

Tags: linux, system-installation

How can I find the time since a Linux system was first installed, provided that nobody has tried to hide it?

Comment: What do you mean by age?

Comment: @Let: The time since it was set up.

Comment: @Tim There is no way to determine that. You could estimate by searching for the oldest files.

Comment: @Let: I was expecting an answer along the lines of "check the timestamp of /some/oscure/file, it is never modified". Please make that an answer.

Comment: I'd say look at the creation date of `/etc` or `/sbin` as a rough and not-totally-reliable estimate.

Comment: @ultrasawblade -- how would you find that?

Comment: Ahh, after researching I found out linux doesn't store this information in its filesystems, but FreeBSD does.  (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/general-10/file-creation-date-in-linux-473684/)  Sorry to mislead you with bad advice.

Comment: Well, look in /etc and find a configuration file related to a program or service that's likely never to have been used.  The `mtime`, visible with the `stat` command, should approximate the date of install.  For example, if no one's ever bothered to change the inittab, that might provide a clue.

Comment: See [the same question on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1352/how-can-i-tell-what-date-ubuntu-was-installed), which has both Ubuntu-specific and more generic answers.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7149/installation-date-of-ubuntu/7157#7157

Comment: Isn't that a bit like asking the age of [Theseus' ship](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)?

Comment: When every part of a linux installation has been replaced over the years, is it still the same installation? (Same as the original analogy of a ship that had all of its parts slowly replaced) I ask because my root partition has changed disks and filesystems, and my home partition is older than that. Some appliances are prepared once as gold images, then get custom hostnames, ssh host keys and fs uuids on deployment. Gold images can be modified and frozen again, like the turnkey linux lineage.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 **OR** /dev/sdb1*  | grep 'Filesystem created:'
```

This will tell you when the file system was created.

* = In the first column of `df /` you can find the exact partition to use.

Comment: Usually `/dev/sda1` or something like that (whatever `df /` shows in the first column), but the principle is sound.

Comment: Hey, that's handy to know, thanks. And this information survives copying the filesystem too. +1.

Comment: The solution is good, but filesystem dependent and requires root privileges.

Comment: +1. However, i have to note that my current desktop was created around 1994.  Absolutely everything about it has changed multiple times since then (including the disks, and the filesystem type i use) but it's still the same system.  This method will only, at best, tell me the date of the most recent move to a new filesystem.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer because it works only with ext2 (maybe up to ext4?) which I don't use.

Comment: Cool solution. It worked even on a system where I used `dump` and `restore` to replace the system drive. But I guess it won't work if you use other methods, such as `cp -a` or `rsync`, to copy the data to the new drive.

Comment: sudo tune2fs -l $(df / | tail -n 1 | awk -F' ' '{ print $1 }') | grep 'Filesystem created:'

Comment: But this not support xfs filesystem?

Answer (score 30):

Check the date of the root filesystem with dumpe2fs.  I can't really think of how that could be anything other than the date you're looking for:

```
dumpe2fs $(mount | grep 'on \/ ' | awk '{print $1}') | grep 'Filesystem created:'
```

Comment: ... or `tune2fs -l`

Comment: You forgot to mention that this is only applicable to ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystem.

Comment: You'd get the wrong date on several of my machines, where I've upgraded hard drives, and just copied the install over.

Comment: @derobert, I still think my answer would be correct, given the OPs question.  A new disk isn't any different from new RAM -- you still have the same 'installation' even though you popped a new disk in...

Comment: @pboin No, when I copy the install over, its a larger disk, so I repartition and mkfs (then use tar/cp to copy it, not dd). May even be a different filesystem (e.g., ext2 -> ext3 -> ext4) So you'd get the time I copied the install over. That's how it could be other than the date OP is looking for.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a new disk: a filesystem upgrade alone would change that date.

Answer (score 22):

There are a few dates lying around.

- All files have dates.
- Log files have dates in them.

On Debian or Ubuntu and their derivatives, see `/var/log/installer/syslog` for the definitive answer if it exists it is part of the log of the instillation.

But beware this is not guaranteed. (see other answers/comments for some of the reasons it may not work.)

Comment: This might be specific to Debian/Ubuntu though.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: Same file/directory is used for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I said specific to Debian/Ubuntu. Meaning the recipe would work for both Debian and Ubuntu, but possibly not for other (non-Debian-based) Linux distributions.

Comment: But not all files HAVE A CREATION DATE. AFAIK birth date was only introduced in ext4, and that is not POSIX anyway.

Comment: @KonradGajewski But nether this answer, or any of its comments mention file creation date.

Comment: This did not work on my Debian Testing system (installed as Linux Mint Debian Edition –and later transitioned to the more sane Debian Testing– in Mar 2014 according to the [dumpe2fs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9990/87770) answers).  Instead, try `ls -ltc --full-time /etc` to list the contents of `/etc` by order of creation time as noted in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310397/87770) below.

Comment: @gerlos your edit (not approved), could be a new answer. Add it as an answer and I will up vote it (if I notice, may be add a comment here, we should delete both comment afterward).

Answer (score 20):

On Red Hat based distributions (e.g. CentOS, Scientific, Oracle etc) you can use:

```
rpm -qi basesystem
Name        : basesystem
Version     : 10.0
Release     : 7.el7
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: Mon 02 May 2016 19:20:58 BST
Group       : System Environment/Base
Size        : 0
License     : Public Domain
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Tue 01 Apr 2014 14:23:16 BST, Key ID     199e2f91fd431d51
Source RPM  : basesystem-10.0-7.el7.src.rpm
Build Date  : Fri 27 Dec 2013 17:22:15 GMT
Build Host  : ppc-015.build.eng.bos.redhat.com
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla>
Vendor      : Red Hat, Inc.
Summary     : The skeleton package which defines a simple Red Hat Enterprise Linux system
Description :
Basesystem defines the components of a basic Red Hat Enterprise Linux
system (for example, the package installation order to use during
bootstrapping). Basesystem should be in every installation of a system,
and it should never be removed.
```

or

```
rpm -q basesystem --qf '%{installtime:date}\n'
Mon 02 May 2016 19:20:58 BST
```

Comment: How come `rpm -qi` gives me `Install Date: Mon 07 Jul 2014 03:20:44 PM UTC`, while `tune2fs` says `Filesystem created: Sat Dec 20 23:41:41 2014`?

Comment: On my Azure's VM all have the same time, so rpm is not reliable at all

Answer (score 13):

The solution most neutral to filesystem and distribution (that I can come up with) is to use the oldest file given by `ls -lact /etc`, which looks at each file's metadata for the creation time.  While this can be gamed, it is not affected by `touch` or files created by extracting archives (e.g. `tar -p` to preserve timestamps).

I think it's best to look at files rather than directories since directories *do* change their creation time metadata when their contents change (perhaps somebody can shed light on why that is?)

```
ls -lact --full-time /etc |tail
```

Systems that lack [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) should remove the `--full-time` option (the sort order will still be correct and you'll still get the day).  You can get the creation time from a file's metadata with `stat FILE |grep Change` (run that on the oldest file listed by `ls -lact`).

On other non-Linux systems, `stat` likely has that information in a slightly different arrangement, possibly requiring different flags.  Note that this still uses the file's metadata and accuracy isn't guaranteed.

Also note that `stat` from GNU Coreutils has a "Birth" time which tends to be wrong (Linux with [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) yields `0` to indicate it's unknown, FreeBSD with [UFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System) showed a "Birth" time that is older than the system I queried).  The correct value was listed as its "Change" time.

If you want to get fancy and get *just* the creation time of the oldest file in`/etc`:

```
ls -lact --full-time /etc |awk 'END {print $6,$7,$8}'
```

This command worked for me on an old FreeBSD system (UFS, no GNU utils):

```
stat "/etc/$(ls -act /etc |tail -1)" |awk -F\" '{print $6}'
```

<sup>(Yes, this parses `ls` and that's taboo, but there shouldn't be mischievously named files in `/etc`.)</sup>

You can also use `stat` to get other time formats.  For example, to get the creation time in [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): `stat -c %Z FILE` (with GNU, note that `%Z` is "time of last status change" but that's the correct flag for my Linux and BSD systems, as noted above; `%W` is the "time of file birth") or `stat -f %c FILE` (with BSD).

Comment: This didn't work for me (a few files were much older than the installation date). But looking only at symbolic links in /var and /etc seems to work: `ls -lact --full-time /var | grep ' ->' |  tail -4; echo; ls -lact --full-time /etc | grep ' ->' |  tail -4`

Comment: @ndemou – What version of `ls` are you using? On what filesystem? I wonder about the validity of the creation times you're seeing; `ls` may be ignoring/misinterpreting `-c` and/or the filesystem may not be storing it correctly. Interesting idea on the symlinks. You could do your trick more simply with `find /etc /var -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0 |xargs -0 ls -lactd |tail -n4`

Comment: `ls` is ver.8.2 and filesystem is xfs. `stat` also shows Change and Modify times that match `ls` output (FWIW it's a CentOS 7 server)

Answer (score 8):

In Fedora, anaconda installer stores the config details of your install in root's home folder, that can give you some idea.

On Debian (at least more recent ones), several logs from the install are stored in `/var/log/installer/`. Older versions stored them in `/var/log/installer.*`. That's at least back to 2003.

Answer (score 6):

```
ls -alct /|tail -1|awk '{print $6, $7, $8}'
```

Answer (score 5):

I have been looking for similar tool, and the best I could come up with was `ls -lAhF /etc/hostname`, simply the age of the hostname file. I think, generaly, the hostname of a system is set at the beginning, and left unchanged during the life of the system. The date of the creation of the filesystem is certailny helpful, but can be misleading. I, for example, often use virtual machines image, which I have installed some time ago, copy it, change the hostname and make a new server from it. Therefore, in my case `/etc/hostname` is better indication than `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 4):

As requested by OP.

If you are looking for the time, when the system was setup, there isn't a way to determine that. For one, the system might have been cloned (not installed) which would effectively fake the file creation time.

You can estimate the age by searching for oldest files.

Comment: mattdm is right; you can get access time, modification time, and change time; ctime is the last. See [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79809/what-is-the-difference-between-file-modification-time-and-file-changed-time)

Answer (score 3):

I look at the oldest file in /boot (top of "ls -ltr /boot". Often there is an original boot sector from the first install there. On my oldest system this gives the date of original installation, despite having replaced everything in the machine and copied the contents of the file system around a few times :)

Answer (score 1):

Since a time ago, I usually install at the sime time that the linux distribution a package called **Tuptime**, which keeps useful statistics about the running time, startups, shutdowns...

For your questions, the line "System life" have that information. As example:

```
System startups:    110   since   10:15:27 08/08/15
System shutdowns:   107 ok   -   2 bad
System uptime:      4.04 %   -   1 days, 22 hours, 4 minutes and 44 seconds
System downtime:    95.96 %   -   45 days, 13 hours, 57 minutes and 30 seconds
System life:        47 days, 12 hours, 2 minutes and 15 seconds

Largest uptime:     2 hours, 10 minutes and 44 seconds   from   20:49:17 09/08/15
Shortest uptime:    9 seconds   from   10:23:36 08/08/15
Average uptime:     25 minutes and 8 seconds

Largest downtime:   7 days, 10 hours, 17 minutes and 26 seconds   from   06:09:45 10/08/15
Shortest downtime:  15 seconds   from   19:27:24 19/09/15
Average downtime:   9 hours, 56 minutes and 42 seconds

Current uptime:     23 minutes and 33 seconds   since   21:54:09 24/09/15
```

More info: https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice script which attempts to provide the OS installation date for various operating systems using various techniques: https://github.com/dmbaturin/scripts/blob/master/installdate.sh

Answer (score 1):

For a simpler solution, you could just do:

```bash
stat --format=%w /
```

This will tell you when the root of your filesystem was created.

---

You also could do just this:

```bash
stat /
```

Advantages:

- Extremely easy to remember.
- No need for `root` privileges, or `sudo`.

Example of the *unfiltered* result.

```
$ stat /
  File: /
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 10302h/66306d   Inode: 2           Links: 21
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2023-12-13 21:08:27.833202790 +0100
Modify: 2023-11-27 11:19:52.611063992 +0100
Change: 2023-11-27 11:19:52.611063992 +0100
 Birth: 2018-06-16 11:26:24.000000000 +0200
```

where the last line is relevant.

Comment: Thank you for the direct result method. I knew about `stat /`, but anyway. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`ls -alct /root`               -> root home directory is created at install time

Comment: But it might have changed afterwards. The time on `/` is slightly less likely to have changed if the kernel isn't kept in `/`, but it's still not a very good indicator. (Reminder: `-c` is not the creation time, it's the metadata change time. Most unix filesystems do not store a file's creation time.)

Comment: show me any time which cannot be changed :)

Comment: The question had the assumption “provided that nobody has tried to hide it”. The ctime of `/root` is likely to change naturally (e.g. every time someone creates a file there).

Answer (score 0):

If you used LVM during the installation, you can check the creation date of a Logical Volume done on the installation day, example :

```
$ sudo lvdisplay /dev/mapper/KUbuntu_VG-rootFS | grep Creation
  LV Creation host, time kubuntu, 2014-12-28 20:52:15 +0100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way

```
# rpm -q -last basesystem
basesystem-10.0-7.el7.noarch                  Tue 11 Jul 2017 03:57:52 PM UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with virtual machines, some of the file system etc were created when the image was created, can be long before the instance was created.

The time stamp on `/etc/locale.conf` seems  modified when the instance is boot up during instance creation.  This might be a good time to use unless the locale is modified later on.

The `/etc/hostname` is similar, except that we do modify it in certain situations.

Any idea as to other files that are modified when a instance is created but not modified thereafter?

Answer (score -5):

I found a simple file. name "1". Maybe is the first file.

```
▶ ls -lact --full-time /1
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 2017-03-23 12:02:46.880994133 +0800 /1
```

Comment: why downvote. This time is really point out the last system installed time.

Comment: I don't have this file on my Linux.