# Finding PC uptime from first day until now

Tags: ubuntu, logs, uptime

I need to find PC uptime from the day of installation until now.

Is this logged somewhere? Does any file log this cumulative uptime?

Comment: First day since manufacture?

Comment: No, First day from OS installation(ubuntu)

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @jippie I need to find PC uptime from first ubuntu installation day until now for loggin in my Company.

Comment: @chalist no you can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As log-files are usually deleted after some time, the total up-time is difficult to get.

If the hard disk is as old as the PC, the RAW value (last number) of

```
smartctl  -a /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours
```

could give a rough estimate how many hours the PC was used.

Comment: I tried. Not worked.

Comment: @chalist As you're using Ubuntu, you'll also find this information via the GUI `Disk Utility`, but it will give you the uptime since manufacture, not since installation.

Comment: @Bernhard I will PC uptime not Disk creation time.

Comment: @chalist I know, therefor my remark, but I commented because it adds something to the answer given by

Comment: Power_On_Hours--0x0032--095--095--000--Old_age--Always---4583. Which is PC uptime ?

Comment: 95 hours or 4583(as minute)?

Comment: @chalist As I wrote in my answer: The last number in the line shows how many hours your harddrive was on. Therefore: 4583 hours =  ~ 191 days.

Comment: -Use it with sudo, this just because the permissions...  

sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Power_On_Hours

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep track of this -from now on- you can use **uptimed**

It's available as package in Ubuntu and Fedora and probably other distributions as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you have some server, use commands like:

```
$ uptime 
$ w
$ last
```

HDD SMARTCTL is also good try.

Also from installation could be information about date created of some files in filesystem. Think about, which files were created with installing of your system?

If you have linux, look at the date of creation of your /root/ directory.
If you have windows, it will be worse...

Answer (score 1):

Install **tuptime**, since that moment, you will have a track of the system uptime.

https://github.com/rfrail3/tuptime

Comment: Indeed, is the better tool to find the historical uptime.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the filesystem, the superblock might have the date the filesystem was created. You'd want to check the root filesystem. [There is more information here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9971/how-do-i-find-how-long-ago-a-linux-system-was-installed)

Comment: Not really related to the asked _uptime_.

Comment: I inferred that he meant the time the system was installed, since he kept referring to installation. The actual uptime is easily obtained.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this command to find the very first moment of the system creation:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda | grep 'Filesystem created:'
```